# Python searching through lists for aspects of tuples

Tags: python, list, search

I have a list of tuples formatted like `((x,y),type)`, and I want to see if the list contains the "type" that I want, regardless of the `(x,y)` position. If it does, I want to insert something right after the index of the tuple containing the selected "type".

The way i have it set up, the list will only contain one of each type, if that makes a difference.

EDIT:

Wow, I'm sorry, I just realized that using dictionaries would make this a lot easier. I promise I did actually think about this before I posted.

Comment: Now I'm using dictionaries, and it works fine. Thanks.

Comment: I was about to say, dictionaries would make the lookup much easier. I'd also take a look at `OrderedDict`, if that's helpful.

Comment: @Treesin -- I was going to propose using a dictionary.  You should post your solution so that others might benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work -

```
for t in l:
    if isinstance(t[1], type):
        l.insert(value, l.index(t))
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, to do this, I just set up each type as its own entry in a dictionary, with the position that it is at as the corresponding entry.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a dictionary out of your list:

```
table = {type:(x, y) for x, y, type in tuples}
```

Now, you can look up a tuple just by doing `table[your_type]`.